# How to install and use npm-python-shell correctly?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, node-modules, npm-install

After installing with the command **"npm install python-shell"** I can't even import the package into the .js file
My intention is to run a simple python script using node.js

The following error occurs in the browser and I can't find a solution in any documentation on the internet

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

async function main() {
  alert ( 'Hi')
}
main();
```

The **require('python-shell')** command produces the following error

```
util.js:602 Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
    at Object.promisify (util.js:602)
    at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/python-shell/index.js.events (index.ts:39)
    at newRequire (python-shell_test.e31bb0bc.js:47)
    at localRequire (python-shell_test.e31bb0bc.js:53)
    at Object.parcelRequire.index.js.python-shell (index.js:17)
    at newRequire (python-shell_test.e31bb0bc.js:47)
    at python-shell_test.e31bb0bc.js:81
    at python-shell_test.e31bb0bc.js:120
```

I'm running the code on a Mac /OS X where python-3 is installed and being used normally.

I would be very grateful for any information that helps me find a solution as there is no reference to this type of problem. thank you very much in advance